# How to convert Pytorch autograd.Variable to Numpy?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor

The title says it all. I want to convert a `PyTorch autograd.Variable` to its equivalent `numpy` array. In their [official documentation](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/tensor_tutorial.html) they advocated using `a.numpy()` to get the equivalent `numpy` array (for `PyTorch tensor`). But this gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "stdin", line 1, in module
>   File
>   "/home/bishwajit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/variable.py",
>   line 63, in **getattr**    raise AttributeError(name) AttributeError:
>   numpy

Is there any way I can circumvent this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Two possible case

- **Using GPU:** If you  try to convert a cuda float-tensor directly to numpy like shown below,it will throw an error.

  > x.data.numpy()
  >
  > *RuntimeError: numpy conversion for FloatTensor is not supported*

  So, you cant covert a cuda float-tensor directly to numpy, **instead you have to convert it into a cpu float-tensor first, and try converting into numpy, like shown below.**

  > x.data.cpu().numpy()
- **Using CPU:** Converting a CPU tensor is straight forward.

  > x.data.numpy()

Comment: How does this compare to `x.cpu().data.numpy()` and `np.asarray(torch_tensor)`? Can't find any documentation that mentions this

Comment: If you want to keep training a tensor on GPU, you'd have to duplicate the numpy array then run `x.data.cuda()` after this, no? (or would the numpy array remain.. perhaps?)

Answer (score 7):

I have found the way. Actually, I can first extract the `Tensor` data from the `autograd.Variable` by using `a.data`. Then the rest part is really simple. I just use `a.data.numpy()` to get the equivalent `numpy` array. Here's the steps:

```
a = a.data  # a is now torch.Tensor
a = a.numpy()  # a is now numpy array
```

Comment: This only works if a is a CPU tensor, if it's on GPU, it'll fail (see @blitu12345's answer)