# Convert PyTorch CUDA tensor to NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

How do I convert a `torch.Tensor` (on GPU) to a `numpy.ndarray` (on CPU)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Pytorch autograd.Variable to Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340848/how-to-convert-pytorch-autograd-variable-to-numpy)

Answer (score 13):

Use `.detach()` to convert from GPU / CUDA Tensor to numpy array:

```
tensor.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

Comment: You only need to call `detach` if the `Tensor` has associated gradients.  When `detach` is needed, you want to call `detach` before `cpu`.  Otherwise, PyTorch will create the gradients associated with the Tensor on the CPU then immediately destroy them when `numpy` is called.  Calling `detach` first eliminates that superfluous step.  For more information see: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/should-it-really-be-necessary-to-do-var-detach-cpu-numpy/35489/8?u=zayd

Answer (score 6):

```
some_tensor.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

---

- [`.detach()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html) detaches from the backward graph to avoid copying gradients.
- [`.cpu()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.cpu.html) moves the data to CPU.
- [`.numpy()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.numpy.html) converts the `torch.Tensor` to a `np.ndarray`.

Answer (score 5):

If the tensor is on `gpu` or `cuda`, copy the tensor to `cpu` and convert it to numpy array using:

```
tensor.data.cpu().numpy()
```

---

If the tensor is on `cpu` already you can do `tensor.data.numpy()`. However, you can also do
`tensor.data.cpu().numpy()`. If the tensor is already on `cpu`, then the `.cpu()` operation will have no effect. And this could be used as a device-agnostic way to convert the tensor to numpy array.

Comment: **NOTE:** Using `tensor.data` without detaching may have unintended consequences, [as explained here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6990#issuecomment-384680164) and [here](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-0_4_0-migration-guide/#what-about-data).

Comment: Is there any option to convert the tensor to integers?