# PyTorch: initializing weight with numpy array + create a constant tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following code :

```
self.wi = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings, embedding_dim)
self.wj = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings1, embedding_dim)
self.bi = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings, 1)
self.bj = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings1, 1)

self.wi.weight.data.uniform_(-1, 1)
self.wj.weight.data.uniform_(-1, 1)
self.bi.weight.data.zero_()
self.bj.weight.data.zero_()
```

I want to initialize the weights with numpy array, and I want to create a constant tensor, which is also a numpy array.
I am new to PyTorch, and I appreciate any help.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you might want to split up your question into separate parts (initializing with the `numpy.array`, and then also a different question about the constant tensor). Otherwise, you can generally look for answers on how to initialize embeddings with other values, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710537/pytorch-gensim-how-to-load-pre-trained-word-embeddings)

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize embedding layers with the function `nn.Embedding.from_pretrained()`.

In your specific case, you would still have to firstly convert the `numpy.array` to a `torch.Tensor`, but otherwise it is very straightforward:

```
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np

# This can be whatever initialization you want to have
init_array = np.zeros([num_embeddings, embedding_dims])

# As @Daniel Marchand mentioned in his answer, 
# you do have to cast it explicitly as a tensor, otherwise it won't work.
wi = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(t.tensor(init_array), freeze=False)
```

The parameter `freeze=False` is important if you still want to train your network afterwards, as otherwise you would keep the embeddings at the same constant values.
Generally, `.from_pretrained` is used to "transfer" learned embeddings, but it does work for your case, too.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look at converting a numpy array into a torch tensor [How to convert Pytorch autograd.Variable to Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340848/how-to-convert-pytorch-autograd-variable-to-numpy)

Comment: I need to initialize the tensor not convert it

Comment: I don't think it should matter, see https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nn_tutorial.html